# Distort (transform) Mesh by formula

Tags: mesh

I have a simple explicit formula F(x,y,z) = (f1(x,y,z),f2(x,y,z),f3(x,y,z)) and a mesh.

As an illustrating example (not the actual one) F(x,y,z) = (x+0.1*y*y,y-0.1*x*z,z+0.1*z*x), and say that the mesh is the usual monkey head.

I would like to modify the mesh by changing the position of each vertex but not the structure of the mesh. I want to do it one go: I am not creating an animation. There already are plenty of tools/modifiers that do that. However, I want the change of position to be precisely given by applying F to the position (x,y,z) of each vertex of the standard monkey head.

Is there a tool or an addon for that?

Comment: Does this https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_3d_Function_Surface work for you?

Comment: No, it does not, unfortunately: I already have my mesh and I want to transform it by a non-linear map.

Comment: Could you add a sample mesh to your question, and explain how you would generate the coordinates and how the vertices should be picked for the transformation e.g. closest to the generated. Do you want to morph a defined mesh into a procedual?

Comment: I realize that I was completely unclear, let me edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wouldn't a simple script work for you, something like this:

```
import bpy  
obj = bpy.context.object  
verts = obj.data.vertices  
for v in verts:  
    x,y,z = v.co[:]  
    v.co = (x+0.1*y*y, y-0.1*x*z, z+0.1*z*x)
```

Comment: If such a thing can work then it's perfect, I'll give it a try.